# Styling Tables - table-layout:fixed vs td-width:20%

Tags: css, width, overflow, css-tables

About a month ago I asked a question ([Table overflows parent div when td content is too wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963291/table-overflows-parent-div-when-td-content-is-too-wide/24963373#24963373)) regarding tables. I got an answer which seemed to work perfectly.
Yesterday I wanted to design the table again, but noticed that I cannot change the width of a td.

What do I want:

1. I want the header neither to wrap nor the overflow to be shown. The answer from a month ago solved this problem.
2. I also want the yellow td to be 20% wide, instead of exactly 50%.

I have not found an answer yet, because either the first or the second problem is solved, never both.
Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mou018yh/2/), just add/remove comments to see both problems:

```
table {
    width: 90%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    /*table-layout:fixed;*/    1. Problem (Header wraps)
    table-layout:fixed;        2. Problem (td-width != 20%)
}

.header {
    overflow:hidden;
    /*white-space: nowrap;*/   1. Problem (Header wraps)
    white-space: nowrap;       2. Problem (td-width != 20%)
}
```

How can I solve both problems at once?

Comment: This is probably the absolute worst way to fix it but you can just set the green to span over 8 columns and the yellow to span over 2.
in total that would be 10 columns that the text should span over. and because the green spans over 8, that's 80% and the yellow over 2 that's 20%.
surely this could be used for a quick and dirty fix, but I can't think of another way, if I do. I'll be sure to comment on here.

Comment: What do you mean by *neither to wrap*. You want it all in one line?

Comment: @KristoferAronSverrisson Thank you for your answer, it really seems to work. At the moment I am not sure if it'll work in all cases in my program, but it looks promising.

Comment: @LcSalazar Yes, even if a part of the text will be hidden.

Comment: @KristoferAronSverrisson I just talked to a friend of mine: the green td shouldn't always be 80% wide. In some cases it depends on the content (an image) which has a known width (in px). We could make it work by using JS (calculating the image width as percentage of the tr), but that would really be a bad way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that in a table with fixed layout the [column width is dictated by the first row](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout).

You can create 2 dummy cells in the first row, and move the header down into its own row. You also need to make your `.red` column span 3 rows to account for this extra row:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td class="red" rowspan="3">RED</td>
        <td class="dummy-green"></td>
        <td class="dummy-yellow"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="header" colspan="2">TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 
        TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="green">GREEN</td>
        <td class="yellow">YELLOW</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

And make the width of the dummy-yellow element 20%:

```
.dummy-yellow {
  width: 20%; 
}
```

Leave `table-layout: fixed;` and `white-space:nowrap` where they are.

The only issue that I can see with this method is that it creates a 2px (invisible) row above your header.

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mou018yh/4/)

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for the link, I didn't know that before. Similar to the first commenter you suggest a workaround for the td-width problem. Do you know a way the achieve the correct header behavior (no wrap, hide overflow) without using table-layout:fixed? That would solve my problem without a workaround, I suppose.

Comment: Because of the way tables work, I don't think this is possible. Remember tables aren't meant for layout.